Trigging a driver on certain actions
I have searched for a few hours and tried things, but to no avail. At loss atm.
Background:
I'm working on rigged characters imported from Character Creater 4:

A driver that is attached to jaw-root bone drives a shape key on a face mesh.
This driver seems to be added when exporting the character from CC4 to Blender
as fbx, but only on certain rigged characters.
Without the driver the jaw bone won't move during the lip-sync action.
I have multiple lip-sync actions and armature actions on the same character.
I push all the actions to the NLA (shape key actions and armature
actions).
I export the character and it’s NLA tracks to .glb (naming the tracks that will play together with the same name (as said in the gltf add-on docs))

Problem:

In the gltf viewer this driver runs from start and not only when
lipsync actions are run.
It even runs when the character is idle and not supposed to say
anything.
The jaw bone should move on certain actions only, and not on all actions.

Questions:

What causes the jaw bone to move when the action itself doesn't
transform the jaw bone at all?
How can this driver instead be triggered on selected actions (when
the character is supposed to move its lips and jaw) and not on
other actions e.g. when idle?

NOTE: Characters that doesn't have this driver works as expected.
Files (simplified blend and glb):
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/lrxwwcmzltkmsencb4tk9/AC_D1AQZOmUrcpOeWKMH1Yw?rlkey=8xvx6818einregdz284bdyq0t&dl=0
You can study the NLA and the Driver (on the CC_Base_JawRoot bone) in the blend file, and you'll spot the problem with the glb in the Donmccurdy's gltf previewer
Appreciate any pointers, and thanks for your time.
Using Blender 4.2.1

Did you try not pushing the jaw shape key action to NLA? It should be triggered by the dirver, not by an action. If this doesn't solve, please upload a (maybe simplified) version of your blend file.

Thanks @joshsanfelici, I have pushed down the vertex animations, named the track accordingly, so it plays along with the armature action with the same name. I have updated the post with link to the files.

I received a reply from Victor Soupday [the author of the CC/iC Blender Tools add-on] at the Reallusion forum. He kindly provided an explanation and a solution. I'm adding this as an answer to this thread just in case others would stumble into the same issue.
BTW I realize my questions and assumptions were a tad off, but I'm learning :)
"The drivers aren't exported from CC4 or Blender, they are set up as part of the add-on [CC/iC Blender tools]. It sounds like they are overriding the jaw bone movements when Blender is exporting the animations.
The reason I had to do it like this is because iClone controls the jaw and the eyes from the facial expressions, but also, all the face capture tools (for Blender and iClone) record only the expression blend shapes and ignore face bones, even for eye movements. So people were getting confused why the Jaw or the eyes weren't moving...
But it's optional and you can disable this behaviour:

Go to CC/iC Pipeline Tab > Character Build Settings panel
Expand the Build Settings foldout
Uncheck all the driver options.

This will stop the shape key drivers getting set up when importing new characters.
Then press the Remove Drivers button to remove them from any existing characters."

The solution is not straightforward, but point is that in your file there's a shapekey which is animated, and this animation drives the jaw bone, while it should be the opposite for a correct glb export: the bone should be animated, and that animation should trigger the shape key.
As many shape keys are animated, depending of the project, the workflow, and the number of animation involved, you could try to fix this animation only, inverting the driver direction (bake the animation to an empty using Copy transform constraint, then using the empty to bake the animation to the bone, then deleting the old driver and setting a new one from bone to shape key), or investing time in building the rig so that every shape key has a bone that drives its value.
Hope it can help!

Josh, thank you very much for looking into this! The first part of your answer is totally understandable. I don’t know why IC8/CC4 chose to do it this way. The second part I think I understand. Will look into it. Rebuilding the rig is a no go for various reasons. I’ll post a comment when I hit a snag trying to follow your solution. I will mark it as accepted. Thanks again!

Josh, I posted an answer that explained and solved the issue. I received a reply from the author of the add-on I use for the import. Thanks for your efforts -  I really appreciate it!

Perfect, thank you.
